# how to access a variable when a global and local variable of same name are already present(c++)?

Tags: c++, global-variables, local-variables

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x = 1;
void fun()
{
    int x = 2;
    {
       int x = 3;
       cout<<::x<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to know is, is there any way to access the x with value 2 in the braces inside the function fun. When I write x it prints 3 and when ::x it prints 1. So how to access x with value 2. and whether we call it a global variable or local variable.

Thanks

Edit 1: Asking Just For Knowledge, wanted to know whether such thing is possible or not.

Comment: This is not possible. If there are nested blocks. It will create confusion only. Why do you want to access it.?

Comment: What do global and local mean to you?

Comment: I was just asking whether its possible or not, for knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know is, is there any way to access the x with value 2 in the braces inside the function fun.

There is no way to access it. The only ,,hack'' to access it is:

```
int x;
{
    int &xOuter = x;
    int x;
    // use xOuter here to access x of outer scope
}
```

> whether we call it a global variable or local variable.

It's a local variable.

I recommend against this practice, it causes confusion. To avoid this, use a compiler option, like gcc's `-Wshadow` to get a warning for cases like this.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice idea.
That's what I was Asking